# pregmatch "debug" from /new/debug.php

Tags: php, preg-match

My preg_match is really bad, can't find they correct formula to take php page.

I try to check in the header, what page now is open with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

possible variants are index, debug, login, register etc.

I want to make a switch what will check with preg_match, and then will switch to field of opened page, where will be executed script for opened link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in this way without preg_match:

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$page = basename($url["path"],".php");

switch($page) {
    case "debug":
        // do something
        break;
    // and so on
}
```